# Simple exercice Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, theory

I have a test tomorrow and I have a doubt about inheritance in java.

Question:
Suppose a program in java where Y is a subclass of X. Suppose that the following code is valid in the program:

```
Y[] vetY = new Y[3];
X[] vetX = vety;
```

Is the following assignment  valid or not in this program? Justify.

```
vetX[0] = new X();
```

My answer(not sure): It is not valid because `vetX` has the methods of `Y` and I don't know what was implemented in Y. So it can compile but it will not run.

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: I did: http://ideone.com/l3pXpJ (supports @Pshemo's answer up to the point where `vetx[0] = new X();` will throw the `ArrayStoreException` (not the access of the stored stuff)).

Comment: "So it can compile but it will not run." is a little contradictory or ambiguous. The program will "run", but it may or may not throw an exception (see other answers for that ;)). "running" and "throwing an exception" are quite different. The program will not run if, say, there is not enough RAM to start the JVM.

Comment: Yes. I tried and I had the following message. run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: X
 at X.main(X.java:9)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

Array created via `new Y[3]` can hold only objects of type `Y` or its *subclasses*. It can't store instances of *superclasses* like `X` because there is risk that `X` will not have all methods available in `Y`, so even if

```
vetx [0] = new X();
```

compiles fine (vetx is type of `X[]` so compiler doesn't see anything wrong here), later you could try to access this object via `vetY` (which is type of `Y[]`) and try to invoke

```
vety[0].getPropertyAddedInY();
```

which instance of `X` will not have.

So to prevent such situation **at runtime** each array checks what type of data someone is trying to put in it and in case it is unsupported type will throw `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation is fine as compiler sees we are defining a reference to its type. 
But at runtime JVM sees that it is pre-declared to store child types and when trying to store the parent type, the reverse definiton (child reference = parent obj) is not possible, so throws an exception.

It can be better understood by the following example-

```
class X {
    public void xMetod() {
        System.out.println("Called xMetod!");
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    public void yMethod() {
        System.out.println("Called yMethod!");
    }
}

public class InheritanceWithArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X[] vetx= new Y[3];     // if new X[3] - then outputs in Called xMetod!
        vetx [0] = new X();     // Runtime exception-  java.lang.ArrayStoreException: X
        vetx[0].xMetod();   
    }

}
```